# event.preventDefault prevents ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to get an ajax call to work inside a function triggered by an onclick event. When I use event.preventDefault the page is not reloaded but the ajax call does not work, no data is added to my database. When I comment out that line the page is reloaded but everything else works.

```
function clickFunction(elem) {
    var var1 =  elem.id;
    var var2 =  var1.split("_");
    //  elem.preventDefault();


    if (var2[0] == "Add") {
        if (var2[1] == "Calls") {
            console.log("Calls");
            console.log(var1);
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.post('progressSheetDynamic', data).done(function (response){
                $(".1").html(parseInt($('.1').html(), 10)+1);
                Calls.update(50);

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Html code

```
<form action="{{ route("progressSheetDynamic") }}" method="post" id= {{ $addID }}>
    <input name="increment" value="increment" type="hidden"> </input>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value= {{$activities}} >
    <button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton" onclick="clickFunction(this)" id= {{ 'Add_'.$newText }}> + </button>
</form>
```

I have checked the logs and the function is going into the if statement. I have also tried using preventDefault on the button click event, by doing elem.preventDefault(); but this does not work. Neither does using return false.

Comment: It would be easier if you formatted your code. Don't make it *harder* for people to help you.

Comment: Add an error halndler

Comment: Fastest way: add `return false;` to your `onclick`. `onclick="clickFunction(this); return false;"`

Comment: Where did `event` come from?

Comment: I tried this but it stops the ajax call from working as well, same as preventDefault().

Comment: You do not declare event, that is why it fails. If you do not want a form to submit, than do not use a submit button.

Comment: Change `onclick="clickFunction(this)"` to `onclick="clickFunction(this, event)"` and add the `event` parameter to your function, like: `function clickFunction(elem, event) {...`

Comment: I am using safari.

Comment: Hmm, I thought Safari had the global event object. Maybe not.

Comment: @squint I have tried what you have suggested but it doesn't work. Inside function clickFunction(elem, event) I am still using event.preventDefault(); though I am assuming that that line would stay the same

Comment: What errors do you get in the developer console?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` call after the `event.preventDefault()`, does it show up?

Comment: You say the data doesn't go to the database. Does your server show the POST request showing up at all? Have you checked the Network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: ...ah, `var data = $(this).serialize();` should be `var data = $(elem.form).serialize();` The `this` will be a reference to the `window` object, whereas `elem` is the `button` so `elem.form` will be the form to serialize *(assuming that's what you wanted)*.

Comment: Thank you that is the solution

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post it in an answer so it can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be with this line:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

It should be this instead:

```
var data = $(elem.form).serialize();
```

The `this` value in your function will be a reference to the `window` object, whereas `elem` is the `button` so `elem.form` will be the form to serialize *(assuming that's the data you wanted)*.

And as noted in the comments, `event` is only defined as a global variable in some browsers, so you need to pass `event` in the attribute and receive it in the function to be safe.

Attribute:

```
onclick="clickFunction(this, event)"
```

Function:

```
function clickFunction(elem, event) {
  // ...
}
```

Note that IE8 and lower do not have `event.preventDefault()`, but you can set `event.returnValue = false` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`event` will not be defined because yuo haven't passed it. You're passing the button through with `onclick="clickFunction(this)`.

Change it to `onclick="clickFunction(event)"`.

Then change the function declaration:

```
function clickFunction(event) {
    console.log(event)
    ...
}
```

If you want both the button and the event, look at what I have:

```
<button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton" onclick="clickFunction(event, this);" />

<script>
    function clickFunction(event, elem) {

        console.log(event);
        console.log(elem);
        event.preventDefault();
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elem will be referencing the button when you pass `this` to `clickFunction(this)`

But button does not have a `preventDefault()` function, thus you will get a `Uncaught TypeError: elem.preventDefault is not a function`

Second, $(this) is referencing window, which should be $(elem.form) instead.

Below is how I fixed your original problem without changing your structure.

Html: (Not passing `this` in `clickFunction`)

```
<button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton" onclick="clickFunction()" id= {{ 'Add_'.$newText }}> + </button>
```

Javascript: (use event.target for elem, $(elem.form) for $(this) )

```
function clickFunction(event) {
    var elem =  event.target; // event.target will be equivalent to your elem 
    var var1 =  elem.id;
    var var2 =  var1.split("_");
    event.preventDefault();


    if (var2[0] == "Add") {
        if (var2[1] == "Calls") {
            console.log("Calls");
            console.log(var1);
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $(elem.form).serialize(); // should be elem.form here to get correct data
            $.post('progressSheetDynamic', data).done(function (response){
                $(".1").html(parseInt($('.1').html(), 10)+1);
                Calls.update(50);

            });
        }
    }
}
```